# Is this map bijective? Is there an inverse?

Tags: functions, inverse-function

Is this map bijective? Is there an inverse?
$f: \Bbb N_0 \rightarrow \Bbb Z$, $n \mapsto 
\begin{cases}
n/2,  & \text{if $n$ is even} \\
-{(n+1)}/{2}, & \text{if $n$ is odd}
\end{cases}$

If so, how do I show this?

Thanks

Comment: Show that it is injection and surjective. Because it is bijective, then there is an inverse as well

Answer (score 1):

If it is bijective it must be both injective and surjective.

Injective (1-1).  For every y in the co-domain, there is at most 1 x in the domain that maps to it.

Surjective -- For every y in the co-domain, there is at least 1 x in the domain that maps to it.

If a function is bijective, then there is an inverse.

Comment: How would I do that with a piecewise function?

Comment: It would be pretty natural split the codomain into the postitive integers (including 0) and the negative integers.  Does every positive integer have a number that maps to it?  It sure does.  How about the negative integers.  Yes, the function is surjective.  Is it ever the case that 2 numbers in the domain map to the same number in the co-domain?  No.